# What does set logtarget Syslog 2 mean in logrotate.conf file?

Tags: centos, centos7, fail2ban, logrotate

I am using latest version of CentOS with NGINX.

My Logrotate.conf file has two blocks/directives for fail2ban log (maybe it was a mistake by my previous hosting provider). Therefore, I am receiving an error of duplicate entry for /var/log/fail2ban.log

The first one is:

```
/var/log/fail2ban.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    size 30k
    create 0600 root root
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/fail2ban-client set logtarget SYSLOG 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

The second one is:

```
/var/log/fail2ban.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    postrotate
      /usr/bin/fail2ban-client flushlogs >/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

I understand that I have to remove one. But, first I want to know what does `flushlogs`and `set logtarget SYSLOG 2` mean? Which block should I delete?

I really searched a lot on the web but there is not enough resources available about the configurations of Logrotate.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `set logtarget SYSLOG` was the method of log rotation before [flush logs](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/b5d6310d281c1c45112ffb285c77a858da99d6f6) was implemented and available in fail2ban v0.8.12.

So delete the first one (assuming centos has a fail2ban >= 0.8.12).